# How can I get only the value from an Excel cell when a formula has been used in it

Tags: python, excel, robotframework

I need only the value of a cell, not formula.

When I use "Get Cell Value" all I get is a formula, like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(MOD(VALUE(CONCATENATE(B1;D1));31);W3:X33;2)
```

I can't open Excel in read-only mode because I first have to generate the value I want to copy

I am using RPA.Excel.Files

This all should be done in **Robot Framework** (I am not familiar with Python)

Could you please help me? (Today is already the third day that I am trying to solve the problem...)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved: instead of using RPA.Excel.Files for reading, you have to use RPA.Excel.Application.
Read From Cells   sheetname   row   column

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).